# header doesn't show properly in low resolution monitors

Tags: html, css

I have a header in my web page with white background color. it works properly in PC monitors. but in mobile phones, the result is something like this:

http://uupload.ir/files/j0ki_screen_shot_2015-10-10_at_19.44.32.png

when I scroll the page to left, half of my header doesn't exist.

http://uupload.ir/files/o0j3_screen_shot_2015-10-10_at_19.50.36.png

my code is here:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .my-header-box{
width:100%;
background-color:#fff;
border-bottom:1px solid #4ba028;
    }

    .my-header-wrapper{
        width:100%;min-width:940px;max-width:1280px;
        height:200px;
        /*border:1px solid #ff0000;*/
        margin:0 auto;
    }

    .my-logo img{
max-width:300px;
max-height:90px;
    }
</style>

<div class="my-header-box">
    <div class="my-header-wrapper">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because you have `min-width:940px;` on `.my-header-wrapper` , the mobile is smaller...try use media queries - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've fixed a width - `min-width` for `.my-header-wrapper`, which is why you are seeing it that way on smaller devices.

```
.my-header-wrapper{
    width:100%;
    max-width:1280px;
    height:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Otherwise, use media query for devices with 939px or less pixels devices.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 936px){
    .my-header-wrapper{
        min-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css `min-width:940px` is the main reason it`s happening.

If you want to make the website more responsive when viewing it in mobile devices try using css media queries

See a simple tutorial here
[W3Schools tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

And if you really want deep understanding then this will be major help:
[CSS-tricks - Media Queries](https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

CSS tricks is going to be real helpful for learning anything around CSS